# ADB connection Error ,In Android studio app does not run even not show any device

Tags: android

[image][image]When i run my project app ,it does not show any running device to run my app.
it shows some error like this image .help me to solve this.[image]

Comment: What does `adb devices` show?

Comment: It shows Nothing .

Comment: after open a project it shows ADB connection error.

Comment: Run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`. If that doesn't work make sure that your SDK is updated. If that still doesn't work download SDK files at a new location and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this
Go to tools then android then enable adb integration.
Then open Bluestack or emulator first then run your project.